# How do I keep whitespace formatting using PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, ascii

I'm parsing text from a file and storing it in a string.  The problem is that some of the text in the original files contains `ASCII art` and whatnot that I would like to preserve.  When I print out the string on the `HTML page`, even if it does have the same formatting and everything since it is in `HTML`, the spacing and line breaks are not preserved.  What is the best way to print out the text in `HTML` exactly as it was in the original text file?
I would like to give an example, but unfortunately, I was not able to get it to display correctly in this markdown editor :P
Basically, I would like suggestions on how to display `ASCII art in HTML`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

use the <pre> tag (pre formatted), that will use a mono spaced font (for your art) and keep all the white space

```
<pre>
text goes here and here 
             and here and here            Some out here
     ▄             ▄█▄ █▄       ▄
 ▄█▀█▓ ▄▓▀▀█▀ ▀▀▀█▓▀▀ ▀▀    ▄█▀█▓▀▀▀▀▀▓▄▀██▀▀
██  ██ ▀██▄▄ ▄█  ▀ ░▒ ░▒   ██  ██ ▄█▄ █▀ ██
█▓▄▀██  ▄ ▀█▌▓█    ▒▓ ▒▓   █▓▄▀██ ▓█ ▀▄  █▓
█▒  █▓ ██▄▓▀ ▀█▄▄█▄▓█ ▓█   █▒  █▓ ▒█  ▓█▄ ▒
    ▀▒           ▀  ▀ █▀       ▀▒  ▀  █▀  ░

</pre>
```

You might have to convert any <'s to &lt; 's

Answer (score 17):

the `<pre>` and `</pre>` might not be ideal in textarea etc..

When wanting to preserve new line - `\n` and `\n\r` use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) as mentioned by UnkwnTech and Brad Mace.

When wanting to preserve spaces use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace):

`str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $stringVariable);`

When both use this:

```
$result = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $stringVariable);
$result = nl2br($result);
```

Comment: Warning, this will make certain words break. Like I had some text and the word "how" was broken on two lines almost like h<br>ow so make sure to test thoroughly.

Answer (score 6):

When you print the data use [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert `\n` and `\r\n` into `<br>`

Answer (score 6):

For all those searchng for preserving  the text  fetched from database , this worked for me , setting CSS as following  ,

```
pre {
     white-space: pre-line;
     text-align : left;
  }
```

in html :

```
<pre >
     <?php echo htmlentities($yourText ) ; ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

just echo the necessary special characters (\s, \n, or \r ) along with your string in your PHP code.

```
<?php 

echo ("hello world \n")

?>
```