# PHP New Line Not Working

Tags: php, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP echo'd text lose it's formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706461/why-does-php-echod-text-lose-its-formatting)

I cant get the new line to function work right. It just comes out as one line. Like this -

```
Make: Sony Model: a Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo
```

This is the code for it ---

```
$message="Make: " . $_POST['make'] . "\r\n Model: " . $_POST['model'] . "\r\n Processor: " . $_POST['processor'];
```

When this is sent as an email it works perfect but when i do

```
echo $message;
```

it just comes out as the above - it all on one line. How can i make this work?

thankyou

Comment: does my name look like rodger? lol - no its not duplicate.

Comment: @user977229 It's a dupe nonetheless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are presumably echoing this onto a web page.

Browsers do not (or at least, should not) respect literal new lines, you have to use the HTML `<br>` tag instead.

Try this:

```
echo str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),'<br>',$message);
// or
echo nl2br($message);
```

Comment: thankyou, how can i incorporate the <br> tag into the code?

Answer (score 3):

HTML ignores newlines.

Instead, you should use `<br />`, `<pre>`, or `<table>`.

Comment: Genuine question (not sarky comment): `<table>`?? How does that work?

Comment: @DaveRandom Just use a table to display tabular data instead of formatting text?!

Comment: Oh right I see. Sorry, I thought you were saying that putting it in a table would render the line breaks. Not paying attention. +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want print it using HTML you'll either need to use `<br />` or use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br/) function.

Using `<br />`:

```
$message = 'Make: ' . $_POST['name'] . '<br />'; //...
```

If you want to send plaintext, set an appropriate HTTP header, e.g.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Most browsers will take this as a hint to display it in 'raw mode'.