# php nl2br not working with output of passthru and shell_exec

Tags: php, c++, shell-exec, nl2br, passthru

I have a program (written in cpp) which outputs some text lines. Each line starts on a new line. On the commandline this program works well. To test the code I used both `fprintf (stdout, "some text\n");` and `'cout << "some text" << endl;'` to produce newlines.

When I use `passthru` or `shell_exec` in a php-script, the newlines disappear - as expected - in my webbrowser. The newlines do appear when I use curl, though (which is good):

```
   $command = "/home/test/myprogram 2>&1";
   $data = shell_exec ( $command );
   echo $data;
```

To print the newlines in the webbrowser, I tried lots of php code to replace newlines with 
 tags, but nothing seems to work, including examples from a related SO question ([PHP New Line Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929975/php-new-line-not-working)):

```
   echo nl2br($data);
   echo str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),'<br>',$data);
```

I guess the failure has to to with my usage of `passthru` or `shell_exec`, but I can't figure how to solve my issue.