# PHP_EOL doesn't work on XAMPP

Tags: php, eol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP echo'd text lose it's formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706461/why-does-php-echod-text-lose-its-formatting)

I got strange problem.
Let's say I got code like this:

```
<?php

class Bar
{
    private $foo;
    function __construct ($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function testFoo($obj)
    {
        echo $obj->foo . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$obj = new Bar("obj");
$obj2 = new Bar("obj2");
$obj->testFoo($obj);
$obj->testFoo($obj2);

?>
```

And well instead of getting expected result which is:

> obj
>   obj2

This is what I get:

> obj
>   obj2

It's just like PHP_EOL represents blank space. I also tried to use "\n" but this one works same. I'm using latest XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are viewing this in your browser, it's because browsers interpret newlines in HTML as regular space characters.

In HTML you need to use `<br>` for forcing a line break.

Comment: Or you can send your output as plain text using `header('Content: text/plain');` - depends on what you're doing.