# How to format concatenated exception strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I am using `flask` and `socket.io` to transmit `python` exceptions, and show the exception strings in an `html` modal box. The problem is the strings displayed in the modal box has no format, which looks like a long concatenated string with all the exceptions put together,

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection raise err File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection sock.connect(sa) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 301, in connect raise error(err, strerror(err)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

and I like it to be displayed like in the `python console`,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 301, in connect
    raise error(err, strerror(err))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am wondering how to achieve that in `JavaScript`.

Update

This is my `js` code for modal box using `<pre>`,

```js
function show_modal(row, column) {

  var modal_header = $(".modal-header");
  modal_header.text("header_footer");

  $(".modal-body p").append("<pre>" + "Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw) File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection raise err File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection sock.connect(sa) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 301, in connect raise error(err, strerror(err)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused " + "</pre>");

  var modal_footer = $(".modal-footer");
  modal_footer.text("header_footer");

  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Wrap the string in `<pre>`. First search result for "html keep formatting": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656/how-do-i-keep-whitespace-formatting-using-php-html

Comment: @ChrisG the problem is if the error is too long, it will stick out the modal box, so how to wrap the error and display the stick-out part in a new line.

Comment: @ChrisG tried to apply `word-wrap: break-word;` or `text-wrap:normal;` to the `modal-body` didn't seems to wrap the text to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code removes essential formatting.

Here's working code:

```js
var err = "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py\", line 137, in _new_conn (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)\n  File \"/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py\", line 91, in create_connection raise err\n  File \"/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py\", line 81, in create_connection sock.connect(sa)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gevent/_socket3.py\", line 301, in connect raise error(err, strerror(err))\nConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused ";

function show_modal() {

  var $pre = $("<pre>").html(err);
  $(".modal-body p").append($pre);

}

show_modal();
```

```css
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap
}

.modal-body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid silver
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p></p>
</div>
```