# How Can I Indent Code Without Sacrificing Whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML5 code.

```
        <code>
            public class Testing {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                }
            }
        </code>
```

But on the page, it puts it on one line and doesn't use the proper indentation.

I know I can use the `<pre>` tag to make it work the way I want, but the problem with using that tag is that it will indent the code too far to the right and if I move the code to the left, it will mess up the whitespace and indentation of the HTML code. Is there anyway I can make the code appear the way I want on the page, without having to sacrifice whitespace and clean HTML code? Thanks.

EDIT: This is different from the potential duplicate because it uses the pre tag and does not address the problem of sacrificing whitespace.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36658/7389264) to [How do I keep whitespace formatting using PHP/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656/how-do-i-keep-whitespace-formatting-using-php-html).

Comment: Add a css rule that formats a pre tag to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian's answer is fully valid but won't work if your "absolute" text indentation is not exactly the same between each code block in your HTML file. Unfortunately, I can't see how CSS can do better than that.

You can also use a script that scan the code blocks (by class in the example but you can use `getElementsByTagName` instead. It runs as page is loaded and look at the first significant line in each node and assumes that the same amount of spaces must be removed at each line.

As a downside, this way can have some strange visual artifacts as spaces are removed when using plenty of blocks.

```js
function parseCode() {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete" ) {
    const nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('code');

    for(let node of nodes) {
      const lines = node.innerText.split("\n");      
      const first = lines[0].length ? lines[0] : lines[1];
      const output = [];
      let read = ' ';
      let spacesToRemove = 0;
       
      while(read === ' ') {
        read = first[spacesToRemove];        
        
        if(read === ' ') spacesToRemove++;        
      }
      
      lines.forEach(line => output.push(line.substr(spacesToRemove)));
      node.innerText = output.join("\n");
    } 
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", parseCode);
```

```css
.code {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<pre>
                 public class Testing {
                      public static void main(String[] args) {
                            System.out.println("Hello World");
                      }
                 }
</pre>

<code class="code">
                 public class Testing {
                      public static void main(String[] args) {
                            System.out.println("Hello World");
                      }
                 }
</code>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing something like this, but I wanted to see if there was a simpler way of doing it. Adrian's way works too, but I think your answer works better and is probably better practice in the long run. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a css rule that formats a pre tag to your liking.

```css
.code {
  margin: 0 0 0 -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  standard
<pre>

<pre class="code">
  styled
<pre>
```