# White Spaces in PHP HTML

Tags: html, css

Good day! I just start working with php html and i have a question on how can i put whitespaces between the Registraion Form and Edit Registration Form. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
<div style="padding-left:380px;">
<a href="add.php"> Registration Form </a>
<a href="edit.php"> Edit Registration Form </a>
</div>
```

Output must be:

```
           Registration Form           Edit Registration Form
```

Comment: The best way would be to add CSS styling to the div, e.g.: `div > a {margin-left: 30px}`. Better to add a specyfic name to div class like `<div class="menu"...` and then use it as a reference in CSS `.menu > a {margin-left: 30px}`.

Comment: sounds duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656/how-do-i-keep-whitespace-formatting-using-php-html

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="padding-left:380px;">
    <a style="margin-right:50px" href="add.php"> Registration Form </a>
    <a style="margin-left:50px" href="edit.php"> Edit Registration Form </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Show him the comparison, how to separate the css, `div > a { ... }`, to use cascading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
put **&nbsp**(no space)**;** inside **''**.

```
str_repeat('&nbsp;', 10); // adds 10 white spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to achieve this but here's one. This should be done using CSS, not point in using actual spaces here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="add.php">Registration Form</a>
  <a href="edit.php">Edit Registration Form</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  padding-left: 380px;
}

.container a {
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><href="add.php">Registration Form        </a></pre>
```